# How to look up data in an Access table using the UserName Environ

Tags: vba, ms-access, environment-variables

In MS Access, I have a table named `"Table"` with three fields. Besides the `ID` field, I have one field named `"User"` and one field named `"Email"`. Both fields are `"short text"`. The table has two rows, the first: `User = Nobody` and `Email = nobody@yahoo.com`. The second: `User = Somebody` and `Email = somebody@aol.com`.

I've created a Module with the following code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim localUser As String

localUser = Environ("UserName")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table", dbOpenDynaset)

rs.FindFirst "[User] = 'localUser'"

MsgBox rs![Email]

End Sub
```

The local user is `"Somebody"` as shown when performing a: MsgBox Environ("UserName")

When I execute the code, I get a message box with `"nobody@yahoo.com"`.

What I am trying to get is a message box with `"somebody@aol.com"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
rs.FindFirst "[User] = '" & localUser & "'"
```

But you could use *DLookup*:

```
Dim localUser As String

localUser = Environ("UserName")
MsgBox Nz(DLookup("[Email]", "Table", "[User] = '" & localUser & "'"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Gustav! I have been struggling for days trying everything I could think of to get the correct combination of qualifiers around LocalUser but failed every time!